# Vertical slick slider scroll

Tags: css, wordpress, slick.js

I'm working with slick slider now and everything is Ok for PC version. But when it's mobile (starting with 768px), the slides become too long to read all the info and every time 1 slide scrolls and we miss a part of info.

http://bb1group.com/services/- here you can see the problem.

Is there a chance to make slider scroll half a slide or smth?

Comment: Please make a working fiddle or snippet

Comment: Please read through [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question, because we can't really help you like this

Comment: Hi, please read this [Something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) and then create a [MCVE]